# jQuery UI Tabs loading specific link within tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to load only links within a certain div inside the tab, otherwise it should just go to the actual link.

Current the code i use loads all links inside the content in the same tab

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(function(){
        $('#tabs').tabs({
          load: function(event, ui) {
            $('a', ui.panel).click(function() {
              var tabId=$('#tabs').tabs('option', 'selected');
             $('#tabs').tabs("url", tabId, this.href).tabs("load",tabId);
              return false;
            });
          }
        });
      }); 
</script>
```

Tab Page

```
    <div id="sresults" style="width: 520px">
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="mylink.html">Songs</a></li>
            <li><a href="mylink.html">Albums</a></li>
            <li><a href="mylink.html">Videos</a></li>
            <li><a href="mylink.html">Entire Blog</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

And then heres the page inside the tab

```
<div id="content">
<a href="permalink.html">My links</a>
</div>

<div id="navi"><a href="tab?page=2">Next Page</a>
</div>
```

I want the links inside the navi div to load within the tab, but all links outside should go to the actual link

Comment: Are you sure `ui.panel` is a reference to a dom element/jqueryized element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you only want to load the navigation links inside the tab.

If so, just replace

```
$('a', ui.panel).click(function() {
```

With

```
$('#navi a', ui.panel).click(function() {
```

Although, I suggest you use a `class` to select your navigation div instead of using an `id` because you might end up with duplicate `id`s, which could cause problems later on.

Comment: Would it be possible to now have the page scroll back to the top of the tab?

Comment: `$('html').scrollTop(0);` before `return false;` should do it. I'm not sure if that will work for anything other than Firefox and IE8 though.